# ASP.NET chart control comes empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I want to use asp.net chart control, have this code in code-behind:

```
chIstatistik.DataSource =
                SqliteDatabase.ExecuteDataTable("SELECT COUNT(*) as sayi, kategoriNo FROM kisi WHERE kategoriNo = " +
                                                drpCategories.SelectedItem.Value);


            chIstatistik.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "sayi";
            chIstatistik.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "kategoriNo";
            chIstatistik.DataBind();
```

What i want to do is, show the row count on a given "kategoriNo". Is there any mistake in the code? Chart comes empty but i can see the data in datasource.

Thanks

Comment: fyi, your code is suseptible to sql injection attacks.

Comment: @Daniel Can you actually cause an unexpected `DropDownList.SelectedItem.Value` by e.g. changing the `<option>` on the client, or does asp.net protect against that?

Comment: its possible, but its better to be safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code

```
DataTable dt = SqliteDatabase.ExecuteDataTable("SELECT COUNT(*) as Yaxis, kategoriNo as Xaxis FROM kisi WHERE kategoriNo = " + drpCategories.SelectedItem.Value);
DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
// Populate series data
chIstatistik.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindXY(dv, "Xaxis", dv, "Yaxis");
```

KategoriNo should be some name which will be displayed on Xaxis. Hope it helps